# ScrollView bars scroll while Content View does not

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I am writing an application to digitally sign consent forms for a business. In storyboard, I have three views... The main view, a scroll View inside the main view, and then a content view inside the scroll view.

Inside the content view I have multiple labels and buttons. Everything works exactly as it should except for the scroll. I can see the scroll bar moving on the right, but the content view does not change. Here are the constraints that I have for the scroll view as well as the content view

[image: Constraints]

And here is a gif of what's happening to get an idea. Seems like no matter what constraints I set, the same thing always occurs.

[image: Gif showing issue]

There is more stuff at the bottom as you can see in this storyboard image.

[image: Storyboard full view]

Comment: It looks like your top label (the title) is set to the top container layout guide, it needs to be set to the contentview inside the scrollview

Comment: How are the y positions of the labels defined?

Comment: The title label (Eyelash View Extension Form) has a top constraint to "Content View" and then a bottom constraint to the next label. Each label below that has the top and bottom constraints to the labels above and below them. The last three labels at the very bottom do not have bottom constraints.

Comment: Is `My View` your scroll view? Are you also adding views via code?

Comment: Yes it is... not the best name haha. And no views are added via code.

Comment: Should the content view top point be set to the My View not the Safe Area. As the view scrolls the label will stay anchored to the top of the scene otherwise. I think your problem is in constaints.

Comment: Also why is their two safe areas? One inside the scrollview and one outside.

Answer (score 0):

1. You just need safe area for the root view, so you can remove safe area of `My View` by selecting it and open `Size Inspector` then uncheck `Safe Area Layout Guide`

   [image]
2. Set `Content View` constraints: top, bottom, right, left, equal width to `My View`. You notice now there no more `Safe Area` guide inside `My View`.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks to Niall Kehoe, I noticed that it had two safe areas in story board. Therefore I went ahead and rebuilt the entire view from scratch. It wasn't fun, but after setting the constraints the right way, everything started working like it should.

Seems like there was an issue when I was initially putting it all together and constraints were most likely confused by seeing two Safe Areas. Super annoying, but I'm glad I was able to get it fixed. Thanks for everyone's help!